# TypeError: unhashable type in python script using urllib

Tags: python, curl, urllib2, typeerror, urllib

I'm attempting to execute the following curl command in a python script using urllib:

```
curl -H "token:<COMPANY_TOKEN>" -X PUT \
https://<DOMAIN>.ezofficeinventory.com/assets/<ASSET_ID>/checkout.api?user_id=<USER_ID>
```

Here's what I have in Python:

```
import urllib
import urllib2

theToken = <TOKEN>
headers = {"token":theToken}

checkOutUrl = "https://<DOMAIN>.ezofficeinventory.com/assets/<ASSET_ID>/checkout.api?user_id=<USER_ID>"

req = urllib2.Request(checkOutUrl, headers)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
thePage = response.read()
```

I understand this particular error will come up without the following:

```
data = urllib.urlencode(values)
```

but this command has no data and works fine from a shell prompt.

Comment: Oops! Nope, that's a typo--but it's not in the script I'm running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to pass off the headers as the request body, the `data` argument. Don't pass those headers in as a positional argument, use a keyword argument instead:

```
req = urllib2.Request(checkOutUrl, headers=headers)
```

Comment: Hmm, now I get the following error:
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

Comment: @GoombaStomp: you can use something like `http://httpbin.org/get` to compare the curl command line result with the `urllib2.Request()` result to see if there are any other crucial differences, but I don't see any from the redacted information you have given us.